# select query manipulating with dates

Tags: sql, oracle, date, between

I have a table with 2 date columns. The start_date and end_date. I am trying to get the data where the date is covered or inside from the start_date and end_Date. I have no idea yet on how to create the query.

[image: Employee leaves table]

I need to get the emp_id who has a leave on April 9 and 10. Someone please help!
Thankss!

Comment: A "SELECT query" is "SQL", not "PL/SQL"

Comment: I am using pl/sql language. Thanks for the clarification. Do you have any idea on how to do this? I appreciate the help

Comment: I am not sure what result you are after, but you are probably looking for `where start_date >= date '2020-04-17'  and end_date <= ...`?. Why do you think you need a stored procedure for that?

Comment: considering tha I don't know the max or min value of their leaves. I am handling thousands of data. Their leaves may start last march and end in may which still covers April 9 and 10

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand what you are after. You apparently have some "date" as the input and you want to check the leave dates against that.

Comment: is there any way that I can use April 9 and 10 in the where condition which should be covered in their leaves?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking for a single leave, then:

```
select l.*
from leaves l
where l.leave_start_date <= date '2020-04-10' and
      l.leave_end_date >= date '2020-04-09';
```

This works for a range of dates, assuming one leave covers them.

If you have distinct dates, use aggregate:

```
select l.emp_id
from leaves l
group by l.emp_id
having sum(case when date '2020-04-09' between l.leave_start_date and l.leave_end_date then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when date '2020-04-10' between l.leave_start_date and l.leave_end_date then 1 else 0 end) > 0 ;
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This is what I've been looking for :)